# Curl HTTPS returns empty string, how to set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST in Linux shell / bash script

Tags: shell, curl, sh

I have simple shell script that uses curl to get a response from a remote URL. The issue is that I migrated the said URL to HTTPS and now curl return an empty string. It seems that setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST option should fix the issue but how do I set this option in a shell script? Any other options / workarounds?

```
#! /bin/bash
URL=$(curl -u user:pass -A "Mozilla" https://example.com/ddns/update.php)
```

Comment: Try `curl -L` to follow any redirects. Otherwise, use `--insecure` to disable the SSL check

Comment: @0stone0 That did not work, but I noticed I am getting Error 500 in browser, any clue why seeing as this is after login? Is it expected for curl to return empty for server errors?

Answer (score 0):

Today, I happened to have the same issue. neither `-k` and `--insecure` nor `-L` worked, but then for some reason I mixed them and it worked.

I can't say why that happened, but this worked for me:

`curl -kL https://...`

PS: it was a Jupyter notebook server. my guess is that it uses both ssl and redirection.